# Using position:absolute on child divs sticks them together into one place

Tags: html, css

I have a number of divs with the same class, that I want to align vertically inside their container div.

The html part looks like this example:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element">
        ........
    </div>

    <div class="element">
        ........
    </div>

    <div class="element">
        ........
    </div>
</div>
```

I have floated the elements (divs with .element class) 'left' so they are all on one row. So far so good no problem yet.
The contents of the .element div vary. Now by default, they are aligned top, and I want to align them to the bottom using this css:

```
#container {position:relative;}
#container .element {position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

Works and does align them to the bottom, but unfortunately it also sticks them together and they all look like they are in one place as one div, the one on top of the other.

Trying to set width, margin, padding etc.. to the .element div does nothing, they just act as one div.
What do I need to do to separate them ? I believe giving each div a separate class is not the right solution.
I also would not like to use table solutions, unless there is absolutely no other way.
I have tried vertical-align:bottom which for some reason does nothing.

I kept searching for long about this but nothing related comes up on the net, so if it's a duplicate I apologize.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide your code in fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is what the position:absolute is all about. I don't see why you use it.

If I understand right you want to vertical align the divs to the bottom and have them appear next to each other / beside each other ? Then most likely you have to modify the display css attribute of your divs to display:inline-block; or even use span tags instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, those are social buttons that I want them all on one row, and floating them left does that fine. I can try display:inline yes.

Comment: success thanks to your idea. I have replaced float:left with display:inline-block to the .element and removed all the rest of the css I had. Now vertical-align top, middle or bottom, works on all just fine. I should have done this before but so many hours of work causes a dizzy head. hope this helps someone else though :D

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `#container` div with another div, set its position to relative, and set the position of  #container to absolute and it's bottom to `bottom: 0`
See [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/DSanK/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just tried this. If I remove the position:absolute;bottom:0; from the .element, then they act as if I've done nothing at all.

Comment: @user1521363 Did you see the example link?

Comment: I just did.. I keep trying things without success so far